# Image in Android

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Я забираю картинки с сайта, но при добавлении в свой лист они отображаются некорректно(сохраняя пропорции, появляются различные отступы). Возможно ли в Android studio указывать размер картинки, считая с центра, так как в Вебе???

Comment: Т.е. вам надо чтобы растягивалось? Не все знают как в вебе

Comment: Попробуйте поэкспериментировать со [scaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: А как в вебе? Учитывайте, что абсолютно не все Android-разработчики попутно являются и веб-разработчиками.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да хотя бы так.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, попробовал растянуть, так на это смотреть страшно. Я хочу брать центр картинки и от центра задать ширину и высоту обрезания. Тогда пропорции сохранятся. Так возможно?

Comment: @DmitriyKoverko, попробуйте scaleType centerCrop или centerInside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучший вариант -  scaleType :centerCrop